# R: summarize based on multiple conditions in dyplr

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to summarize a dataframe to create two summaries:

1. count the number of orders only `QUOT` or `QUOG` appear
2. count the number of orders `QUOT` or `QUOG` appear and where there are other `Holds` appearing too

Below is the start of the code:

```
library(dplyr)


dat <- data.frame(Order = c(123,123,123,145,145,189,210,210,123,123,164), 
                  Location = c("Chicago","Chicago","Chicago","Chicago","Chicago","Chicago","Chicago","Chicago","Charlotte","Charlotte","Charlotte"),
                  Hold = c("QUOT","ENGR","VEND","QUOG","ENGR","QUOT","ENGR","VEND","QUOT","CUST","QUOT")
)


test <- dat %>%
  group_by(Order, Location) %>%

  .....
```

I get stuck with trying to find out if a particular order only has `QUOT` or `QUOG` and then if it has `QUOT` or `QUOG` and others.

Expected output:

```
   Location Only Multiple
1   Chicago    1        2
2 Charlotte    1        1
```

So for the expected output:

- Order 123, Chicago: has `QUOT` in it and another hold (`ENGR` & `VEND`) so this would be considered a ***multiple*** for Chicago
- Order 145, Chicago: has `QUOG` in it and another hold (`ENGR`) so this would be considered a ***multiple*** for Chicago
- Order 189, Chicago: has `QUOT` in it and no other holds so this would be considered a ***only*** for Chicago
- Order 210, Chicago: has neither `QUOT` or `QUOG` so this order gets ***excluded*** in the count
- Order 123, Charlotte: has `QUOT` in it and another hold (`CUST`) so this would be considered a ***multiple*** for Charlotte
- Order 164, Charlotte: has `QUOT` in it and no other holds so this would be considered a ***only*** for Charlotte

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should work -- you may want to test this with a few other Orders:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dat <- data.frame(
  Order = c(123,123,123,145,145,189,210,210,123,123,164), 
  Location = c("Chicago","Chicago","Chicago","Chicago","Chicago","Chicago","Chicago","Chicago","Charlotte","Charlotte","Charlotte"),
  Hold = c("QUOT","ENGR","VEND","QUOG","ENGR","QUOT","ENGR","VEND","QUOT","CUST","QUOT")
)

dat %>% 
    group_by(Order, Location) %>% 
    mutate(
        quot_or_quog = Hold %in% c("QUOT", "QUOG"),
        distinct_quot_or_quog = n_distinct(quot_or_quog)
    ) %>% 
    # Remove those that do not have "QUOT" or "QUOG"
    filter(quot_or_quog) %>% 
    mutate(
        label = if_else(distinct_quot_or_quog == 1, "Only", "Multiple")
    ) %>% 
    group_by(label, add = TRUE) %>%
    summarise(num_label = n_distinct(label)) %>% 
    group_by(Location, label) %>%
    count(num_label) %>% 
    pivot_wider(
        names_from = label,
        values_from = n
    ) %>% 
    select(-num_label)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#> # Groups:   Location [2]
#>   Location  Multiple  Only
#>   <fct>        <int> <int>
#> 1 Charlotte        1     1
#> 2 Chicago          2     1
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Works great! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution using `dplyr` and `tidyr`. This time the pivoting happens first, and then filtering and summarising are done afterward to get to your solution.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dat.summary <- dat %>%
  mutate(hold_count = 1) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Hold, values_from = hold_count) %>% 
  mutate(only = if_else((QUOT == 1 | QUOG == 1) & is.na(ENGR) & is.na(VEND) & is.na(CUST), 1, 0),
         multiple = if_else((QUOT == 1 | QUOG == 1) & (ENGR == 1 | VEND == 1 | CUST ==1), 1, 0)) %>% 
  group_by(Location) %>% 
  summarise(only = sum(only, na.rm = T), multiple = sum(multiple, na.rm = T))

dat.summary
```

gives you:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  Location   only multiple
  <fct>     <dbl>    <dbl>
1 Charlotte     1        1
2 Chicago       1        2
```

DATA

```
dat <- data.frame(
  Order = c(123,123,123,145,145,189,210,210,123,123,164), 
  Location = c("Chicago","Chicago","Chicago","Chicago","Chicago","Chicago","Chicago","Chicago","Charlotte","Charlotte","Charlotte"),
  Hold = c("QUOT","ENGR","VEND","QUOG","ENGR","QUOT","ENGR","VEND","QUOT","CUST","QUOT")
)
```

Comment: I like your answer but didn't choose it because 1) you were the second answer and 2) @JasonAizkains answer provides the 'Other" holds to not have to be named versus yours which does